# Cleaning URL using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

From This:

```
crunchpaper.com/jlpt/form/try_question.php
```

To This:

```
crunchpaper.com/jlpt/try_question/
```

I try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^try_question$ /try_question.php/$1 [NC,QSA]
```

But it's not working.

I want to clean the URL above.

Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This rule should work :

```
RewriteRule ^jlpt/form/try_question\.php$ jlpt/try_question/ [L]
```

Comment: If you need this rule to work for more than one URL, please tell me, i'll update my answer.

Comment: Get rid of the RewriteCond line.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^jlpt/form/try_question\.php$ jlpt/try_question/ [L]

on /var/www/crunchpaper/jlpt


<Files ~ "^\.ht">
deny from all
</Files>
Options -Indexes

# ErrorPage
ErrorDocument 400 crunchpaper.com/
ErrorDocument 403 https://crunchpaper.com/
ErrorDocument 404 https://crunchpaper.com/
ErrorDocument 405 https://crunchpaper.com/


# DefaultPage
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^crunchpaper.com\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://crunchpaper.com/$1 [R=301,L]

on /var/www/crunchpaper

Can you tell me what is wrong
```